# removing "?" only in a specific sub-directory by str_replace

Tags: php, html

The function below is replacing   and `&` and `?` characters but for `?` i want the replace works **only** when in subdirectory `example.com/forum/`

```
public static function clean($sUrl)
    {
        return str_replace([' ', '&', '?'], ['%20', '&amp;', ''], $sUrl);
    }
```

example:

```
https://example.com/forum/post/work/22/what-are-requirements-to-get-a-work-permit?/24
```

to

```
https://example.com/forum/post/work/22/what-are-requirements-to-get-a-work-permit/24
```

Here's the code that is making the forum URL:

```
<a href="{{ $design->url('forum', 'forum', 'post', "$topic->name,$topic->forumId,$topic->title,$topic->topicId") }}">
```

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: It's the forum link i want to remove "?" from forum title. But this function always remove "?" in all other URLs too.

Comment: If you can give some examples by editing your post, it will be much clearer to me.

Comment: Or if it is easier to remove directly from title here is the code:

Comment: <a href="{{ $design->url('forum', 'forum', 'post', "$topic->name,$topic->forumId,$topic->title,$topic->topicId") }}">

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear to me without looking at input and expected output.

Comment: OK, I edited the question, giving all the details.

Comment: Ok, you need to `trim($topic->title,"?")` before passing it to `$design->url()`.

Comment: Could you please edit the code str replace in order to do it? Cause your suggestion needs me to edit a lot of other codes in all my php pages. Also please give it as an answer so i can accept your answer.

Comment: ok, but before that can you clear if `$topic->title` will have `?` only at the end, or it can be in between also?

Comment: it can be in between of a forum title also. For example this title: " why? is it difficult?.."

Comment: seems like a job for `urlencode` or `http_build_query`

Comment: Yes, seems like we have to get the current url and if it's in forum subdirectoty then use the return `str_replace([' ', '&', '?'], ['%20', '&amp;', ''], $sUrl);` instead and for others urls use only `str_replace([' ', '&'], ['%20', '&amp;'], $sUrl);` Can you write the code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the URL string to check if `forum` subdirectory is present in the URL using [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Later, you can use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove `?` from your URL.

```
<?php 

function removeQuestionMarks($URL){
    if(preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\/example\.com\/forum\/.*$/',$URL) === 1){
        $URL = trim($URL);
        $URL = str_replace("?","",$URL);
    }

    return str_replace([' ', '&'],['%20', '&amp;'],$URL);
}

echo removeQuestionMarks('https://example.com/forum/post/work/22/what-are-requirements-to-get-a-work-permit?/24'),PHP_EOL;

echo removeQuestionMarks('https://example.com/forum/ why? is it difficult?/877');
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/FXDml

**Note that** I haven't used `urlencode()` as it would convert other characters in the URL too which is not desired in your case.

Comment: where is the else function? Get the current url and if it's in forum subdirectoty then use the return str_replace([' ', '&', '?'], ['%20', '&amp;', ''], $sUrl); and for others urls use only str_replace([' ', '&'], ['%20', '&amp;'], $sUrl);

Comment: @Smith Glad to help :)

Comment: It works fine but for 100% sure shouldn't i change this in your code: `$URL = str_replace("?","",$URL);` to this: `$URL = str_replace([' ', '&',"?"],['%20', '&amp;',""],$URL);`

Comment: @Smith you can if you wish to, but it won't make a difference as `$URL` is going to come down filtered anyway.

Comment: Ah I see now why it works fine. Good job! I didn't know that. Another thing I'm thinking is can I use instead of example.com a more general value to get domain name instead?

Comment: @Smith you can pass your URL to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php  and then retrieve URL segments from it.